# How to make the values reactive in pinia after fetching data from strapi api?

Tags: vuejs3, strapi, shopping-cart, pinia

I think I'm missing something very basic here, and cannot come around it. Currently I'm building a strapi based ecommerce store, where the frontend is vue3 and I'm trying to allocate data using pinia stores. Now, when trying to push or removing items by id to or from the shopping cart component its not working and i'm not getting errors back from console.

I'm able to fetch data, from the api in the pinia store `ProductStore.js`:

```
import { ref } from "vue";
import { acceptHMRUpdate, defineStore } from "pinia";

const error = ref(null);
const apiUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_STRAPI_URL;

export const useProductStore = defineStore("ProductStore", {
  state: () => {
    return {
      products: [],
      productsFeatured: [],
      cartItems: [],
    };
  },

  actions: {
    async fill() {
      this.products = await fetch(apiUrl + "/api/products?populate=*")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => (this.products = data.data))
        .catch((err) => (error.value = console.log(err)));
    }
},
```

Here is the `ProductsView.vue` component where i'm giving out data for `TheCart.vue` and `ProductCard.vue` component:

```
<script setup>
import { useProductStore } from "@/stores/ProductStore";
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
import ProductCard from "../components/ProductCard.vue";
import TheCart from "../components/TheCart.vue";

const imageLink = import.meta.env.VITE_STRAPI_URL;
const productStore = useProductStore();
const { products, cartItems, addToCart, removeFromCart } = storeToRefs(
  useProductStore()
);
productStore.fill();
</script>

<template>
  <section>
    <div class="pt-10">
      <TheCart
        @remove="removeFromCart"
        :cartItems="cartItems"
        :product="product"
      />
    </div>
    <div
      class="grid grid-flow-row gap-10 sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4"
    >
      <div
        class="text-center mx-auto"
        v-for="product in products"
        :key="product.id"
      >
        <ProductCard
          :product="product"
          :imageLink="imageLink"
          @add="addToCart"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

Here is `TheCart.vue` component where i'm trying to render the list of `cartItems` array:

```
<script setup>
import IconTrash from "./IconTrash.vue";
import { useProductStore } from "../stores/ProductStore";
import { useGetProductImage } from "@/composables/useGetProductImage";
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";

defineProps({
  product: Object,
  cartItems: Array,
});

defineEmits(["remove"]);

const { countCartItems } = storeToRefs(useProductStore());
</script>

<template>
  <div class="flex mx-auto relative flex-col max-w-2xl p-6 space-y-4 sm:p-10">
    <div
      class="flex flex-col max-w-3xl p-6 space-y-4 sm:p-10 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100"
    >
      <h2 class="text-xl font-semibold">Your cart</h2>
      <pre>
        cart quantity: {{ countCartItems }}
      </pre>
      <!-- CART LIST -->
      <ul class="flex flex-col divide-y divide-gray-700">
        <li
          v-for="item in cartItems"
          :key="item.id"
          class="flex flex-col py-6 sm:flex-row sm:justify-between"
        >
          <div class="flex w-full space-x-2 sm:space-x-4">
            <img
              class="flex-shrink-0 object-contain w-20 h-20 dark:border-transparent rounded outline-none sm:w-32 sm:h-32 dark:bg-gray-500"
              :src="
                useGetProductImage(item.attributes.image.data.attributes.url)
              "
              alt="Polaroid camera"
            />
            <div class="flex flex-col justify-between w-full pb-4">
              <div class="flex justify-between w-full pb-2 space-x-2">
                <div class="space-y-1">
                  <h3 class="text-lg font-semibold leading-snug sm:pr-8">
                    {{ item.attributes.name }}
                  </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="text-right">
                  <p class="text-lg font-semibold">
                    {{ item.attributes.price }}
                  </p>
                  <p class="text-lg font-semibold">
                    quantity: {{ item.attributes.quantity }}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex text-sm divide-x">
                <button
                  @click="$emit('remove', product)"
                  type="button"
                  class="flex items-center px-2 py-1 pl-0 space-x-1"
                >
                  <IconTrash />
                  <span>Remove</span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is the `ProductCard.vue` where I'm trying to add the item by id:

```
<script setup>
defineProps({
  product: Object,
  imageLink: String,
});

defineEmits(["add"]);
</script>

<template>
  <div
    class="max-w-xs rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg transition-transform duration-300 hover:-translate-y-1"
  >
    <img
      :src="`${imageLink}${product.attributes.image.data.attributes.url}`"
      :alt="product.attributes.name"
      class="mb-2 px-12 py-12 max-h-60 object-contain w-full bg-gray-200"
    />
    <div class="px-4 py-4 flex flex-col">
      <h3 class="text-primary-100 flex-1">{{ product.attributes.name }}</h3>
      <p class="text-sm mb-4 flex-1">
        {{ product.attributes.description.slice(0, 110) }}...
      </p>
      <p class="font-bold mb-4">{{ product.attributes.price }} Ft</p>
      <AppButton :to="`/products/${product.id}`" class="flex-1 mb-2">
        Megnézem
      </AppButton>
      <button
        class="bg-accent text-white font-semibold px-2 py-3 rounded"
        @click="$emit('add', product)"
      >
        Add to Cart
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And these are the store methods to push/remove/increment/decrement the `cartItems` array defined in `ProductStore.js`:

```
countCartItems() {
      if (this.cartItems.length) return this.cartItems.length;
    },
    addToCart(item) {
      let index = this.cartItems.findIndex((product) => product.id === item.id);
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.products[index].quantity += 1;
      } else {
        item.quantity = 1;
        this.cartItems.push(item);
      }
      // this.cartItems.push(item);
    },
    removeFromCart(item) {
      // this.cartItems.pop(item);
      this.cartItems.splice(
        this.cartItems.findIndex((product) => product.id === item.id),
        1
      );
      this.cartItems = this.cartItems.filter(
        (product) => product.id !== item.id
      );
    },
    incrementItem(item) {
      let index = this.cartItems.findIndex((product) => product.id === item.id);
      if (index !== -1) {
        let index = this.cartItems.findIndex(
          (product) => product.id === item.id
        );
        this.cartItems[index].quantity += 1;
      }
    },
    decrementItem(item) {
      let index = this.cartItems.findIndex((product) => product.id === item.id);
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.cartItems[index].quantity -= 1;
        if (this.cartItems[index].quantity === 0) {
          this.cartItems = this.cartItems.filter(
            (product) => product.id !== item.id
          );
        }
      }
    },
    getCartTotal() {
      //
    },
```

I cannot find out how my dataflow is bad between the components. In the pinia `ProductStore.js` when i'm only trying `this.cartItems.push()` without the id its working.

Can anyone point out the mistakes I'm making with these? Thanks in advance

Comment: After `this.cartItems.push(item)`, try to console log the `cartItems` to see if it is updated

Comment: Its updated, if i try to push it with `id` it breaks